# Execute Ant task just if a condition is met

Tags: ant

I need to execute an Ant task within a specific target only if a condition is met.

I found a way to define the condition at the target level, but not at the task level. I have also found a contribution that implements an [IF task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html).

My question is, are you aware of any way to achieve this objective with standard Ant tasks?

Longer explanation: I am trying to start Tomcat Server in case it is stopped. To detect if it is stopped I use following code:

```
<echo message="Checking whether Tomcat is running"/>
<condition property="tomcat.running">
  <socket server="${tomcat.host}" port="${tomcat.port}"/> 
</condition>
```

So my next task in this target, is an exec task that should be executed only if `${tomcat.running}` is false. And as I said, I don't want to add a single task in a target to use the unless property.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

An Ant target can have an optional `if` or `unless` clause. This means to execute the task only if the property is set, with an `if` clause, or is unset with the `unless` clause<sup>1</sup>. Interestingly, that `if` or `unless` clause is checked ***after*** any dependent task is first executed.

This means, you can do this in standard Ant as a way of executing an Ant task only if a particular condition is met:

```
 <target name="test.if.tomcat.is.running">
      <condition property="tomcat.running">
          <socket server="${tomcat.host}" port="${tomcat.port}"/> 
      </condition>
</target>

<target name="my.target"
    if="tomcat.running"
    depends="test.if.tomcat.is.running">
    <yaddah/>
    <yaddah/>
    <yaddah/>
</target>
```

You specify that you want Ant to execute Target `my.target`. Ant notices that `my.target` depends upon the `test.if.tomcat.is.running` target, and will execute that first. The `test.if.tomcat.is.running` task will set the `tomcat.running` property if Tomcat is actually running. Otherwise, that property is not set.

Finally, Ant will go back to the `my.target` target and see if the property `tomcat.running` is set, and will only execute the target `my.target` if it is set.

Or, you can use the Ant-contrib tasks which may make your entire build process easier to understand.

If you want to go the Ant-Contrib route, there's an easy way to setup Ant-Contrib, so the Ant-contrib jar is actually part of your project. If someone checks out your project from the version control system, they'll also get the Ant-contrib jar, and thus won't have to install Ant-Contrib themselves.

Download the Ant-Contrib jar, and put it into a directory in the root of your project called `antlib/ac`. The `antlib` can be used for all sorts of optional task jars such as [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net) or PMD. Just put each optional Ant jar in their own directory under `antlib` (Like I put Ant-Contrib under the `ac` directory).

Then, in your `build.xml`, you specify the Ant-Contrib tasks this way:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
   <classpath>
       <fileset dir="${basedir}/antlib/ac"/>
   </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

Now, you can use the Ant-Contrib tasks without worrying whether or not they're installed on a particular machine or not. You checkout your project, and you have access to those tasks automatically.

---

**1.** That's right, the `if/unless` clause checks if a property is set and not `true`/`false` which can cause a lot of confusion. I've seen developers set a property to `false` or `no`, and then wonder why the target is actually executing since the `if` clause is set to false.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in the original post I was looking for a way to avoid creating targets. With that solution I need a new target for each conditional execution. From your answer I understand there is no way, and that is the reason of ANT Contrib project. Right?

Comment: Well, you are _creating_ new targets, but these aren't targets that your users will ever use by themselves. Think of them as _internal targets_. It does make following the build process a bit trickier, and is one of the reasons why people like Ant-Contrib. The problem w/ Ant-Contrib task is that they aren't part of the standard Ant which usually means you have to tell people to install Ant-Contrib before they can build your project. However, if you do it the way I stated in the second part of my answer, that is no longer an issue.

Comment: <taskdef reference= should be <taskdef resource=

Answer (score 14):

Since *version 1.9.1*(*) ant supports having **if- and unless-conditions** in a more fine-grained way **on any task**, if you declare the necessary namespaces inside the project element.

(*) *Please, use the latest version of ant (1.9.6 as of this writing), as version 1.9.1 contains flaws WRT this new feature, as user @Rebse kindly pointed out.*

In the example below you can play around commenting/uncommenting the properties...

```
<project name="test"
         xmlns:if="ant:if"
         xmlns:unless="ant:unless">

  <property name="is.good" value="hohoho"/>
  <!--property name="hide.base" value="boo"/-->

  <target name="foo">
     <echo unless:set="hide.base">${basedir}</echo>
     <echo if:set="is.good">GOOD</echo>
  </target>
</project>
```

... and observe outputs such as this:

```
Buildfile: D:\test\ant\taskcondition\build.xml
foo:
     [echo] D:\test\ant\taskcondition
     [echo] GOOD
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 191 milliseconds
```

Comment: You should at least use Version Ant 1.9.3 because Ant 1.9.1 had bugs in the first implementation of if/unless, see https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55885

Comment: Thanks for the note @Rebse

Comment: Official Ant manual for this feature: https://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html

Answer (score 6):

If you want an "if else" kind of implementation:

```
<target name="test.if.tomcat.is.running">
      <condition property="tomcat.running" value="true" else="false">
          <socket server="${tomcat.host}" port="${tomcat.port}"/> 
      </condition>
</target>

<target name="my.target.running"
    if="${tomcat.running}"
    depends="test.if.tomcat.is.running">
...
</target>

<target name="my.target.ifnotrunning"
    unless="${tomcat.running}"
    depends="test.if.tomcat.is.running">
   .....
</target>
```

Comment: This code snippet seems to conflict with https://stackoverflow.com/a/14567297/358658 which stated that if the property it set the target will run, not if the property is true or false.  If a property is set to true or set to false, it is still set.  But the if is supposed to be testing if set or not set.

Answer (score 1):

There are situations when you are not able to make your Ant target dependent on another Ant target because the **if** should be evaluated based on a value initialized just before exec (I can provide a clear example but for simplicity sake I won't).

On Unix like systems an alternative (preferable in certain situations) is the following:

```
<!-- the property that contains the value to be checked agains IF -->
<property name="myprop" value="true"/>

<!-- the Ant's exec combined with OS-IF command -->
<exec executable="bash">
        <arg value="-c" />
        <arg value="if [ &quot;${myprop}&quot; != &quot;$${myprop}&quot;] || [&quot;${tag_exists}&quot; != &quot;true&quot; ]; then my-bash-command _arguments_; fi" />
</exec>
```

In the above the **my-bash-command** illustrates the command/program you want to execute and the ***arguments*** ilustrates the arguments for that command.

Note that when the **myprop** is not set then the ${myprop} will be simply evaluated to the string "$" + "{" + "myprop" + "}" (ie. "${myprop}"), thus we have to compare the value of **myprop** against that string.

On the other hand when **myprop** is set then its value is probably the string **true/false** so in order to check **IF** our condition is met we should compare the **myprop** against the string **true** (or whatever value you may have).

**Conclusion**: using the Ant's **exec** combined with the OS command **IF** we can execute arbitrary OS commands/programs without the need of another Ant target. Using the same logic as above the **IF**-like statement may be tweaked to work even on Windows.